# tsconfig.json compile problem when running mocha tests with overwritten global interfaces

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, mocha.js, tsconfig

I am trying to write tests for my nodejs server application and by now everything worked fine. I can compile my code from typescript to javascript without error and everything but when I try to run mocha tests the typescript pre-compilation fails due to not finding my self defined typings in `typings.d.ts`.

Here are my declarations inside the `typings.d.ts`

```
import {User} from "./users/user.model";
import {MainDatabase} from "./core/models/database.model";
import {Translation} from "./core/services/i18n";
import {LanguageDefinition} from "./core/models/language.model";
import {Reminder} from "./core/services/schedule/schedule.model";
import {UserProfileModel} from "./core/database/models/user_profile";
import {UserClientModel} from "./core/database/models/user_client";
import {PhoneNumberModel} from "./core/database/models/phone_number";
import {CountryModel} from "./core/database/models/country";
import {CustomerTypeModel} from "./core/database/models/customer/customer_type";
import {CustomerModel} from "./core/database/models/customer/customer";
import {ReminderModel} from "./core/database/models/reminder_options";
import {Customer} from "./customers/customer.model";
import {IUserAccount} from "./core/database/models/user_account";
import {UserAccountModel} from "./core/database/models/user_account";
import {MailModel} from "./core/services/mail/mail.model";
import {Request} from "express";
import {Models} from "sequelize";

declare global {
  module NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      translation: Translation;
      db: MainDatabase;

      /*Classes to be reach through the global object*/
      User: User;
      Reminder: Reminder;
      Customer: Customer;
      Mailer: MailModel;
    }
  }

}

declare module "Express"{
  export interface Request {
    user?: IUserAccount;
    authenticated: boolean;
    locals: {
      files?: File[];
    };
    locale?: LanguageDefinition;
    info?:{
      userAgent?: string;
      ip?: string;
    }
  }
}

// extending the original sequelize interfaces
declare module "sequelize" {

  /**
   * Database models
   * only list SEQUELIZE Models here not classes
   * */
  interface Models {
    UserProfile: UserProfileModel;
    UserAccount: UserAccountModel;
    UserClient: UserClientModel;
    Reminder: ReminderModel;
    PhoneNumber: PhoneNumberModel,
    CustomerType: CustomerTypeModel,
    Customer: CustomerModel,
    Country: CountryModel
  }
}
```

And in my `app.ts` I'm using those types by importing the original interface / type from the original package

```
//omitted for brevity
/**
 * Setup all globals that do not belong to the database
 * */
private setupServerGlobals() {
  try {
    global.Mailer = new MailModel();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('setupServerGlobals', e);
  }
}

private setupTranslation(): Observable<any> {
  // create translation
  const translation = new Translation({
    language: { language: 'de', fullLanguage: 'de' },
  });
return translation.init().pipe(
  tap(() => {
    global.translation = translation;
  }),
);
}
```

Now when I run `tsc --watch & nodemon ./dist/src/app.js` all files are compiled successfully and the server starts without any problems. My global defined typings inside `typings.d.ts` are seen by the compiler due my tsconfig.json configuration.

But when I run `tsc & mocha` it throws this error:

```
/Users/user/Documents/Project/subfolder/project-name/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:261
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app.ts(60,14): error TS2339: Property 'Mailer' does not exist on type 'Global'.
src/app.ts(78,11): error TS2339: Property 'info' does not exist on type 'Request'.
src/app.ts(156,16): error TS2339: Property 'translation' does not exist on type 'Global'.
```

My setup looks like this:
+ I have all test files next to each to-be-tested file
+ I have an test folder where my `mocha.opts` file is in

Here the contents of my `mocha.opts` file:

```
src/**/*.spec.ts
--require ts-node/register
--recursive
```

And finally here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

## Expectation

To run my tests like it runs the server, without compiling problems.

I appreciate every help.

## Edit

I could solve my problem by just importing the typings from `typings.d.ts` like so in my `app.ts` file

```
import * as typings from './typings';
```

But for me that just don't seem to be a good solution for this problem because in every file I'll use the `global` variable I'll need to reimport the typings like above.

Still feel free to solve this issue if you know how to.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I inserted the following into `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  }
}
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript contains below [typeRoots and types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) configs in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "./typings"
],
"types": [
   "mocha"
]
```

If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included
typeRoots: typings are looked in these folders.

If types is specified, only packages listed will be included. e.g. mocha. If you all packages from typeRoots are required (as in your case) then don't provide the types options. Specifying `"types": []` will disable automatic inclusion of @types packages.

Comment: yeah I know these configs, but they just exclude my typings or the typings inside @types, but I want those typings inside `@types` and my typings inside `typings.d.ts` to merge on compilation.

Comment: is it excluded even if both `"./node_modules/@types"` and  `"./typings"` are provided?

Comment: no of course it works so but the thing is that **only** when I run tests the typings are not recognized by the typescript compiler. when running my server normally (not testing him via mocha/chai .spec files) it works fine.